# Linking.addEventListener not working (using expo)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am trying to listen to the url changes with `Linking.addEventListener` but it's never firing. The url is opened using `expo-web-browser` because I wanted the browser to be opened in-app.

My code:

```
  const buyNowHandler = async () => {
    try {
      let result = await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync("https://google.com");
      Linking.addEventListener('url', ({url}) => {urlChangeHandler(url)})
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const urlChangeHandler = (url) => {
    console.log("url: ", url);

    WebBrowser.dismissBrowser();
    Linking.removeEventListener("url", urlChangeHandler);
  };
```